# Hybridauth in a new Window

Tags: php, javascript, authentication, cakephp-2.0, hybridauth

I've recently switched to Hybridauth on my Cakephp-Site to offer my users Social-logins.

Right now, the main window loads the Social-Page and then redirects back to my site.

I'm now wondering, if there is any way to do the Authentication in a new Window:

```
User clicks on login button (main window) 
-> new window opens social-login page 
-> users loggs in 
-> the window closes
-> the main window refreshes with logged in user
```

Any idea how this is done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old, but I was looking for the answer myself. I found it in the "widget_authentication" example included with HybridAuth.

Look in the index.php file inside the widget folder. Even if you don't want to use the widget, you can still see exactly how the author opened either a new window or intermediate  plus new window, depending on the provider.